# Remove all matches except first five

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the string of SVG-code like this:

```
<g class="highcharts-legend"  transform="translate(217,262)">
    <g  clip-path="url(#highcharts-9)">
        <g transform="translate(0,0)">
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>1</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>2</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>3</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>4</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>5</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>6</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>7</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>8</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>9</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>10</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

Need to remove all matches `<g class="highcharts-legend-item">...</g>` except first five.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [the `DOMDocument` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for working with svg markup. [Here's a fiddle.](https://3v4l.org/IS4Yi)

```
<?php

$svg = <<<SVG
<g class="highcharts-legend"  transform="translate(217,262)">
    <g  clip-path="url(#highcharts-9)">
        <g transform="translate(0,0)">
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>1</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>2</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>3</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>4</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>5</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>6</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>7</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>8</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>9</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>10</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"></rect></g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
SVG;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($svg);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('g') as $g){
    if($g->getAttribute("class") === "highcharts-legend-item"){
        $items []= $g;
    }
}

for($i = 5; $i < count($items); $i++){
    $items[$i]->parentNode->removeChild($items[$i]);
}

echo $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

> ```
> <g class="highcharts-legend" transform="translate(217,262)">
>    <g clip-path="url(#highcharts-9)">
>       <g transform="translate(0,0)">
>           <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>1</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"/></g>
>           <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>2</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"/></g>
>           <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>3</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"/></g>
>           <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>4</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"/></g>
>           <g class="highcharts-legend-item"><text x="21" y="15"><tspan>5</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#f7a35c"/></g>
>
>
>
>
>
>       </g>
>    </g>
> </g>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation! It works good and helps me for additional conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
(?:<g\ class="highcharts-legend-item">.+?</g>[\n\r]){5}\K
(?:<g\ class="highcharts-legend-item">.+?</g>[\n\r])+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gOfOk9/1) or (better) use a parser instead.